# Reversing a String Using Iterators

Tags: c++

I'm trying to reverse a string (e.g change "bro" to "orb") using iterators. Unfortunately, my code doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
for(std::string text; std::cin >> text;){
    for(std::string::const_iterator it = text.cend() + 1; it <= text.cbegin(); --it)
        std::cout << *it;
}


return 0;}
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Hint: There's also `std::rbegin()` and `std::rend()`.

Comment: `text.cend() + 1` there's nothing there to `*it`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly your code isn't reversing a string, it's printing a string backwards. Not the same thing at all.

The easy way to print a string backwards would be to use a reverse iterator

```
for (auto it = text.rbegin(); it != text.rend(); ++it)
    std::cout << *it;
```

But if you want to do it with a regular iterator then the following works

```
auto it = text.end();
while (it > text.begin())
     std::cout << *--it;
```

Comment: and what does the arrow operator ```-- >```  do?

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker Well I changed that but it was only a combination of post decrement `--` and greater than `>`.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker That's the one of the most famous C++ question on StackOverflow :)) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c